# Can I say "think down" as an alternative of "look down"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrasal-verbs

You know when someone says "people are looking down upon somebody"

Today I asked somebody "will people think down on my code if I do this and that.."

Is this correct?

Looked for this expression in Google, couldn't find it.

Also, should it be "alternative of" or "alternative to" in the title of this question?

Context: In a programmers forum I asked a question how to do a particular task in my code. They offered a few methods, and I said I disliked one of those "best practices" and I would like to stick with a practice of mine. So then I asked "what if other developers look at my code, will they think down on it" meaning "will they think its badly written".

Comment: I like your *will they think it's badly written* more than *will they think down on it*. I personally might say *"When others read my code, will they think it's bad?"*

Answer (score 2):

We don't really "think down on" something, but we can "think lowly of" or "think poorly of" something.

Answer (score 1):

*Look down on* someone is quite a common phrase.

> [Look down on](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/look?q=look%20down#look__66) - regard (someone) with a feeling of superiority.

In that way, "Will people *think down on* my code ..." does not sound okay to me. So, the phrase *think down on* is **not** an alternative to **look down on**.

*An edit after the OP added the context:*

*Will they think it's badly written* is plain, simple and unambiguous. You can certainly go for it as it makes it a better choice.

However, other alternative includes:

> *Will other developers think that my code is not a good practice to follow?*

In fact, I just searched on the Internet and found that for *coding*, *'practice'* is the better word to use in such condition.

Comment: I've edited my question providing context

Comment: You said it! Go with 'will they think it's bad...' version of yours!

Comment: @J.Kowalski so I edited my answer!

Comment: so all in all "think down on/of" is a "no-no" :) actually looking down upon someone is probably coming from the more superior person being taller? or standing straight while the other person is shorter or on their knees. This is how I explain it to myself, so thinking down on someone really doesnt make sense, does it? :)

Comment: Looking down is not about being taller! It's something that I am superior (for example your boss) and consider you *nothing*. In that way, *I often look down on you while discussing ideas in the meetings.*

Answer (score 1):

How about "look down on my code"?

From The Free Dictionary:

**[look down on somebody/something](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/look+down+on):** to consider someone or ***something*** as not important or of value | look down your nose at somebody/something

*“A lot of people look down on us because we're homeless,” she says.*

---

Look down on *or* look down upon

> They **look down on our *efforts*** all the time, no matter how much we try.

Source: [Basic American Grammar and Usage](http://books.google.com.ly/books?id=mHAPSFcgbqoC&pg=PA186&dq=%22look%20down%20on%20our%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kZ5MVMy2M8LtO-3XgIgE&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22look%20down%20on%20our%22&f=false) by Marcel Danesi p.186, Barron's Educational Series, Inc. 2006

---

From the **CORPUS OF CONTEMPORARY AMERICAN ENGLISH**

> These aristocratic and professional families have always *tended to*
>   **look down on business** as something rather distasteful.

Source: What makes peoples rich? (cover story) by Richard Lynn, National Review 1991

> In our time, the dominant class consists of intellectuals (very
>   broadly and loosely defined) and knowledge workers. Its members *tend
>   to* **look down on business** and to elevate freedom of speech and personal
>   morality over the economic freedoms required by a healthy economy.

Source: Individual Liberty and the Constitution by Robert Bork, American Spectator 2008